# EF Fluent API Link table

Tags: entity-framework, fluent

This i my first post ever.

I'm having trouble with EF 5 and the FluentAPI.
The issue is that I'm using a link table which would normally result in a Many-to-Many relationship, but I want only a single entity on the one side of my relationship.
I've managed to get this working using database-first, but can't get it working using code-first.

Here is a basic entity structure :

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual Car Car {get;set;}
}

public class Car
{
    public virtual int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual string Name {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons = new HashSet<Person>();
}

public class PersonCar
{
    public Person Person {get;set;}
    public Car Car {get;set;}
}
```

I'm creating the code-first from an existing database.

The database has the following structure :

```
Person
Id int
Name varchar(200)

Car
Id int
Name varchar(200)

PersonCar
PersonId int, Primary Key
CarId int
```

As you can see, the Person does not have a foreign key to Car. There is a link table used to perform the relationship.
Is there anyway to express this relationship using the Fluent API?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can remove `virtual` from all your non navigation properties:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Car> Cars { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        Cars = new List<Car>();
    }
}

public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    public Car()
    {
        Persons = new List<Person>();
    }
}
```

Then you can map it by overriding the `OnModelCreating` in your context:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Cars).WithMany(p => p.Persons)
            .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("PersonId")
                .MapRightKey("CarId")
                .ToTable("PersonCar"));
    }
```

### Edit

Based on the comments below, something like this would suffice:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CarId { get; set; } 
    // If Car is optional do this: public int? CarId { get; set; }
    public virtual Car Car { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    public Car()
    {
        Persons = new List<Person>();
    }
}
```

You don't need to do anything else (No Fluent API mappings needed)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't have an ICollection<Car> on the Person class. It has to be a single navigation property.

Comment: This configuration is currently working in my database-first edmx.
EF uses the PersonCar table in the store model as a relationship which is then wired up as a single navigation property on Person and a Collection on Car.

Comment: I don't understand why you need the third table when you're only mapping to a single entity on your `Person` class? What that entity is telling me is that each `Person` may only have 1 `Car`..

Comment: Each Person may have only one Car yes. And the same Car can be used by several Person's. As I mentioned, I was given this database structure. A foreign key would have been much easier but I don't have that luxury I'm afraid.

Comment: Regarding the updated approach. Will EF automatically use the PersonCar table?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck with the database design. I have to use the PersonCar table.

Comment: Why? It makes no sense to use it.. can't you just migrate existing data over to the new (improved) schema?